# Incorrect subtotals & Totals in mysql select

Tags: mysql, select, mariadb

I've managed to separate the negatives & positives in the sql select below and I am trying to get the subtotals & totals as indicated in the table pic belom the third column is what the correct results should be.

[image]

Below is sql select I've used but its returning the results in column 2 of the above table and its not correct. How can I get the subtotal & total results in column 3

Thanks & Regards

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT
      party AS "Account",
      sum(debit-credit) AS "Balance"
 FROM `tabGL Entry`
 WHERE party_type ="Customer" AND MONTH(posting_date) = MONTH(Now()) -1
 GROUP BY party WITH ROLLUP
 HAVING sum(debit-credit) < 0
 UNION ALL
 SELECT
      party AS "Account",
      sum(debit-credit) AS "Balance"
 FROM `tabGL Entry`
 WHERE party_type ="Customer" AND MONTH(posting_date) = MONTH(Now()) -1
 GROUP BY party WITH ROLLUP
 HAVING sum(debit-credit) > 0
) rec

 UNION ALL

 SELECT NULL AS party, sum(dep) AS Balance 
 FROM (
 SELECT SUM(credit-debit) AS dep
 FROM `tabGL Entry`
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT SUM(credit-debit) AS nodep
 FROM `tabGL Entry`
) AS recb
 GROUP BY party WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax to prevent `GROUP BY` from being attached incorrectly:

```
( SELECT ... GROUP BY ... )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... GROUP BY ... )
```

Versus

```
( SELECT ...  )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ...  )
GROUP BY ...
```

Where did the word 'Subtotal' come from?  I don't see it in the query.

I suspect the inner `WITH ROLLUP` is tossed.  What happens if you remove them?

Comment: Thanks will give it go. I added the subtotals to the table in excel so they better clarify the result needed, in the actual sql table they are just NULL.